# How can I handle the error and still apply REGEXEXTRACT to other rows in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This formula finds the file ID in one column if the key is found. However, if one key is not found, it seems to stop there, but the other rows below do have the keys ok and the file ID and should display the images. How can I handle these errors, so that the formula works with the rows below?

[Here's the example in a sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(D2:D6;lambda(Σ;image(substitute(substitute(xlookup(Σ;A:A;B:B;);"file/d/";"uc?id=");"/view?usp=sharing";))))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Will it work if the ending is different than `/view?usp=sharing`, for example? Thanks a lot!

Comment: In that case just use your original regexextract formula variant in place of substitute here